# How to read a csv file from s3 bucket using pyspark

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I'm using Apache Spark 3.1.0 with Python 3.9.6. I'm trying to read csv file from AWS S3 bucket something like this:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
file = "s3://bucket/file.csv"

c = spark.read\
    .csv(file)\
    .count()

print(c)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o26.csv.
: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "s3"
```

I understand that I need add special libraries, but I didn't find any certain information which exactly and which versions. I've tried to add something like this to my code, but I'm still getting same error:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3 pyspark-shell'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `hadoop-aws` version 3.2.0 for spark 3. In `--packages` specifying `hadoop-aws` library is enough to read files from S3.

```
--packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0
```

You need to set below configurations.

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "<access_key>")
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "<secret_key>")
```

After that you can read CSV file.

```
spark.read.csv("s3a://bucket/file.csv")
```

Comment: Dunno if it defaults but one should also specify:
```
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.impl","org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
```
Just for sanity...

I'm also using org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common, org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client, and org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws, although may be unnessesary?

this documention is really helpful: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mohana for the pointer! After breaking my head for more than a day, I was able to finally figure out. Summarizing my learnings:

Make sure what version of Hadoop your spark comes with:

```
print(f'pyspark hadoop version:  

{spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.util.VersionInfo.getVersion()}')
```

or look for

```
ls jars/hadoop*.jar
```

The issue I was having was I had older version of Spark that I had installed a while back that Hadoop 2.7 and was messing up everything.

This should give a brief idea of what binaries you need to download.

For me it was Spark 3.2.1 and Hadoop 3.3.1.

Hence I downloaded :
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/3.3.1
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle/1.11.901 # added this just in case;

Placed these jar files in the spark installation dir:
spark/jars/

```
spark-submit runner.py --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.3.1
```

You have your code snippet that reads from AWS S3

Comment: Update: you need aws-java-sdk-bundle- 1.11.901 => else I did get  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProvider