# How to resolve spark error when reading from s3

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

I am getting an error(java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: S3a) when running a spark application.  I have looked through various other questions regarding this type of error, but Im not able to determine the solution.  Spark is version 3.1.2

**Updated details below to reflect current state**

pyspark script:

```
import os
#os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.7.4,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.4 pyspark-shell'
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("s3reader") \
            .getOrCreate()\

sc = spark.sparkContext

#sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
#sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.access.key", "xxxxxxx")
#sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "xxxxxxxxxxxx")
#sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint","xxx.x.xxx.x.com", "us-1-east")
#sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.path.style.access", "true")

df = spark.read.json("S3a://silver/testfolder/4a2426b2-856c-4e9b-b698-b3dcdca74f48")

print(df)
```

here are my jar versions:

```
cloud@spark-dev-master:/usr/local/spark/jars$ ls -ltr *aws*

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloud cloud 126287 Aug 18  2016 hadoop-aws-2.7.4.jar

-rw-rw-r-- 1 cloud cloud   4479 Sep 17 02:36 aws-java-sdk-1.7.4.jar
```

stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cloud/sparks3test.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = spark.read.json("S3a://silver/testfolder/4a2426b2-856c-4e9b-b698-b3dcdca74f48")
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 372, in json
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1304, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.json.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: S3a
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:519)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: I also just tried changing the aws-java-sdk version to 1.7.4 as suggested in other posts and updated the spark-default.conf file to match.  Same error persists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there still appeared to be jar dependecies issues, I did a fresh install on spark using 3.1.2 and hadoop 3.2.0 and aligned hadoop-aws and java-sdk jars with aws-common jar version on the master and worker nodes.  This corrected the file system issue.  Consequently, upgrading to 3.2.0 also corrected the endpoint issue we were running to as well as path.style.access=true is not supported in any hadoop version older than 2.8.0.  That issue was documented here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12963 for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hadoop-aws version 3.2.0.

You can refer my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921060/how-to-read-a-csv-file-from-s3-bucket-using-pyspark/68921812#68921812).

Comment: Thanks for the input, but that did not help.  I updated the hadoop-aws jar to 3.2.0 set it in the spark-default.conf file and added the os.environment line into my code but the same error persists.

Comment: Did you use --packages? Remove the previously added jars on jars folder and use --packages by specifying hadoop-aws3.20. It will download all the required dependencies.

Comment: Just use `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.access.key` and use `s3a://` while reading file instead of `s3://`

Comment: I removed all previous jar files, used s3a instead of s3:// and still error persists.  i will update my code above to reflect current state.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting an error(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/hadoop/fs/StreamCapabilities)

This is what you see when you mix hadoop-aws and hadoop-common JAR versions. They must match point for point (as spark JARs also require).

Do not attempt to work around this except by syncing up JARs, you will only be moving stack traces around.

See Hadoop [troubleshooting s3a](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html#java.lang.NoSuchMethodError_referencing_an_org.apache.hadoop_class)

Comment: Thanks @stevel.  I have made sure that the jar version for hadoop-aws and hadoop-common are the same version (2.7.4) as specified in the Maven repo. I also added the classpath info for driver and executor in to spark-defaults.conf...but im getting No FileSystem for scheme: S3a

Comment: well, it is classpath/version setup problems you have I'm afraid.

Comment: do you mean there still is a version conflict between hadoop-common and hadoop-aws?

Comment: inevitably. I use my cloudstore diagnostics tool to debug hadoop installations here, but it doesn't directly play with spark. Worth me considering how to do that,  in future: https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore